# How to change Shipping Cost per two product in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce plugin in a wordpress site.
The shipping method is to be calculated on the basic of USPS Priority 1-Day mail $5.75 per pound (lbs).

Each shirt ways 1/2 a pound in weight, so 2 shirts should not be charged additional shipping.

Means I want to calculate the shipping method for per two shirt i.e. $5.75 not as cost per product.

then the shipping will be calcalated as like ths

3 -4 shirts $11.50 and 5 shirts $17.25 etc...

The basic requirement is if I would be able to change the shipping cost per product to per two product the query will be solved. How Can I get this method.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I know it is tooooo late but still, asking with two products do you want to fetch price from USPS or this is only flat price ?